# Red Gate comparison not working after upgrading SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Compare Red Gate Red Gate to make comparisons between 2 DBs on 2 different SQL Servers.

For this, I have  created a SSIS package which encompasses an Execute Process Task. I have passed following as an Executable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Red Gate\SQL Compare 10\SQLCompare.exe
```

and as an argument:

```
sqlcompare /Server1:\"server_ip\" /Database1:\"db_name\" /Username1:\"user_id\"
  /Password1:\"password\" /MakeSnapshot:\"E:\Folder\AUDITserver1.snp\"
```

This Execute Process Task is to create a `.snp` file of server 1 and to compare it with server 2. This used to work fine before. However, recently, I have upgraded SQL Server 1 from 2012 to 2016.

I have also re-created a linked server connection for Server 1 on the server where the comparison package is being run. However, I am getting an error. The description is:

> [Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Red Gate\SQL Compare 10\SQLCompare.exe" "
>   sqlcompare /Server1:\"server_ip\" /Database1:\"db_name\" /Username1:\"user_id\" /Password1:\"password\" /MakeSnapshot:\"E:\Folder\AUDITserver1.snp"" at "",
>   The process exit code was "70" 
>   while the expected was "0".

Please help.

I tried running it via command prompt as follows:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Red Gate\SQL Compare 10

sqlcompare /Server1:\"server_ip\" /Database1:\"db_name\" /Username1:\"user_id\"
  /Password1:\"password\" /MakeSnapshot:\"E:\Folder\AUDITserver1.snp\"
  /Options:CaseSensitiveObjectDefinition
```

And now facing an error as follows:

> Unexpected error: A duplicate object name has been found.
>   This may occur if the SQL Server that you are registering is case sensitive but the case sensitive option is not set.
>   RedGate.SQLCompare.Engine.SqlCompareException
>      at #mWo.#KYo.#0cp(DBPopulationOptions #YBCc)
>      at #mWo.#HPud.#crc(ConnectionProperties #x1lc, #en #LfCc)
>      at RedGate.SQLCompare.Engine.Database.#crc(ConnectionProperties #Ap8b, #en #5
>   OPb)
>      at #namb.#n9G.#W8G(DataSource #ovUb, #en #5OPb, Boolean #q9rc)
>      at #i9G.#n9G.#W8G(DataSource #ovUb, #en #5OPb, Boolean #q9rc)
>      at #i9G.#n9G.#1tD(String #p9rc, DataSource #ovUb, #en #5OPb, Boolean #q9rc)
>      at RedGate.SQLCompare.CommandLine.CommandProcessor.#lMPb()
>      at RedGate.SQLCompare.CommandLine.CommandProcessor.#kcmb()
>      at RedGate.SQLToolsCommandLine.CommandProcessor.#OUb()
>      at #i9G.#OsPb.#6sc(String[] #ead)
>   Caused by:
>   Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the colle
>   ction.
>   Parameter name: index
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>      at System.Collections.BitArray.Set(Int32 index, Boolean value)
>      at #8rg.#5sg.set_Item(DatabaseLevelPermissionAction #pYrc, PermissionType #iT
>   c)
>      at #mWo.#KYo.#MCCc()
>      at #mWo.#KYo.#ICCc()
>      at #mWo.#KYo.#0cp(DBPopulationOptions #YBCc)

Comment: Have you opened a support ticket with RedGate?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. But I have edited the question and added some additional info.

Answer (score 1):

If this actually is SQL Compare 10.7 or earlier, I believe it may not work with SQL Server 2016.
https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SC10/SQL+Compare+10.7+release+notes

Comment: We have version 12.4 installed

Comment: But that's not what you showed in the question - your file path is pointing at the SQL Compare 10 directory. Make sure you're pointing it at your SQL Compare 12.4 installation.